# Dependência Circular! criação do objeto

Tags: c++

O Código é bem simples! Eu tenho duas classes aluno.h e diciplina.h e preciso manter uma dependência circular entre elas!

quando estou em aluno.h eu consigo criar um atributo da classe diciplina
usar new, construtor,sets e gets. Mas quando faço alcontrario eu consigo criar
e setar como 0 mas n consigo dar um new e usar :/

[Error] forward declaration of 'class diciplina::aluno' e
[Error] invalid use of incomplete type 'class diciplina::aluno'

Deis de já grato!

```
#ifndef DICIPLINA_H
#define DICIPLINA_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "aluno.h"

#define MAX 20


class aluno;

class diciplina{

    public:

    class aluno;

    diciplina(string codDic,    string descricaoDisc){  

    this->codDic = codDic;
    this->descricaoDisc = descricaoDisc;

    for(int i = 0; i<20; i++) // Inicializa com tudo 0
    dA[i] = 0;  
    }

    ~diciplina(){

    delete[]dA;

    }   
    bool matricula(aluno **al,int id){

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    if(dA[i] == 0){
    dA[i] = new aluno("Fulano","09834534","Computer Science"); //  ESSA LINHA QUE DA ERRO
    return true;
    system("pause");
    }
    return false;   
    }

    private:
    string codDic;
    string descricaoDisc;
    aluno *dA[MAX];


    };  
#endif

    #ifndef ALUNO_H
#define ALUNO_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "diciplina.h"

using namespace std;

class diciplina; // declaracação forward

class aluno
{
    public:

        aluno(string nome, string cpf, string curso){
        this->nome = nome;
        this->cpf = cpf;
        this->curso = curso;    

        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        alunoDiciplinas[i] = 0;
        }
        ~aluno(){       

        delete[] alunoDiciplinas;

        }

        bool matricula(diciplina **dic,int id){

        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        if(alunoDiciplinas[i] == 0){
        alunoDiciplinas[i] = new diciplina(dic[id]->getCod(),dic[id]-   >getDiciplina()); // MAS AQUI NÃO DA ERRO !!
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



        private:        
        string nome, cpf, curso;
        diciplina *alunoDiciplinas[10];

};
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, o problema é que você usa a classe `aluno` antes de ser definida (implementada) e o mesmo não acontece com a classe `diciplina` porque você já a definiu quando foi utilizá-la em `aluno`. Isso acontece porque está fora do padrão do C++, e aí o compilador não aceita.

**Solução** 
Bom, não sei se é a melhor, mas seguindo o padrão do C++ e pelo que entendi do seu código (que ele está separado em `aluno.h` e `diciplina.h`), deixe no `.h` somente a assinatura dos métodos, e suas respectivas implementações em arquivos `.cpp`. Dessa forma, todas as declarações são feitas antes de suas implementações, o compilador sabe trabalhar com isso e então ele aceita.